# How to compare a list of object with an individual object of that type?

Tags: java

this is am learning java now. I just want to know whether should we write any comparator for comparing the list of objects with a particular object? And i also want to know why the particular line is not comparing the list

myList.contains(obj1)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class createItem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] itemid = null;

        try{
            File itemFile =  new File("C:\\"+"Sano"+".xml");
            itemFile.createNewFile();

            List<ObjectIdName> myList = new ArrayList<ObjectIdName>();
            ObjectIdName obj1 = new ObjectIdName("ABC","ABC");

            myList.add(new ObjectIdName("DEF","DEF"));
            myList.add(new ObjectIdName("ABC","ABC"));
            if(myList.contains(obj1)){
                System.out.println("Has");

            }
            System.out.println("MyList:" + myList.size());

        }           
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
class ObjectIdName implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;

    private String name ;

    public ObjectIdName (String id, String name) {
        this.id= id;
        this.name =name;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `equals()` [compares the references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The `equals` method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns `true` if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`).

Since `obj1` and the second object you insert into the list are two distinct objects, `myList.contains(obj1)` returns `false`.

To compare the fields, `ObjectIdName` has to [implements its own `equals()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Note that if you implement `equals()`, it is also a good practice to implement `hashCode()` (even if it's not used by your code).